# A C++ large integer precision question during multiplication

Tags: c++, integer, precision, multiplication

If I run the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace std;

   uint64_t f12 = 18446744073709551568;
   uint64_t f3 = 2;
   uint64_t f123 = f12 * f3;

   cout << f12 << endl;
   cout << f3 << endl;
   cout << f123 << endl;

   return 0;
```

}

I get as output:

```
18446744073709551568
2
18446744073709551520
```

I don't understand why 2 times f12 results in a value that is less (by exactly 48). If the value rolled over due to reaching the size of the uint64 value, wouldn't it be quite different (unless this is an extreme coincidence)?

Comment: Write `uint64_t f12=-48;` and it will look less surprising. Or print `-f12` and `-f123`.

Comment: The value you're doubling is equal to 2^64 - 48  (using ^ to represent exponentiation)    Doubling it mathematically produces 2^65 - 96.   That is greater than the range of a `uint64_t`, so subtract 2^64, which gives 2^64 - 96.    The difference between that and the original value is 48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chalk it up to "extreme coincidence". 18446744073709551568 in binary is

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFD0
```

We all discovered when we learned binary math that multiplication by two is equivalent to a left shift, which becomes:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFA0
```

Note that `D0` is

```
11010000
```

in binary, with the high bit set, so shifting left the lower 8 bits becomes

```
10100000
```

or `A0` (with the high bit getting carried left).

And now, by computing what's `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFA0` in decimal you'll get the answer to your question (you are kind of getting a clue already, since `A0` is less than `D0` by `30` hexadecimal, which happens to be, purely by accident, 48).

Comment: Sam, I now see that.  Not so much a coincidence, after all, since I was playing with Mersenne primes, and 2^61-1 ended up being a "seed" value, which got me within a factor of 8 of the 2^64 roll over limit.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying an integral value by 2 can be seen as a left shift of the bits. When you convert your number `18446744073709551568` to binary, then this is...

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111010000
```

If you shift these bits one left, then the result is...

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110100000
```

In the least significant byte, i.e. at the right end, `11010000` (decimal `208`) is replaced by `10100000` (decimal `160`), which is exactly your `48` less. All the higher significant bytes remain the same. So the overall result is `48` less, too.

Answer (score 0):

The shifting is a red herring.

64 bit unsigned math in C++ is math modulo 2 to the power 64.  If 2*a is 48 less than a, then a is 2 to the power 64 minus 48.